# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors Diagonilization

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $ A=\begin{bmatrix}
        -7 & -1  \\
        12 & 0 \\  \end{bmatrix} $ . Find a matrix $ P $ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $PDP^{-1} = A$.

Ok so the first thing I need to look for are my eigenvalues and eigenvectors. However, I think I'm doing it wrong and don't seem to get the correct eigenvectors.

If $ det(A-\lambda I)X=0 $ then
$ det(\begin{bmatrix}
        -7-\lambda & -1  \\
        12 & -\lambda \\  \end{bmatrix})= \lambda^2+7\lambda+12=0 $

This gives me eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-3 $ and $\lambda_2 = -4 $

---

Case: $ \lambda_1 = -3$

$ \begin{bmatrix}
        -7-(-3) & -1  \\
        12 & -(-3) \\  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        -4 & -1  \\
        12 & 3 \\  \end{bmatrix} $ and end up with eigenvector
$\begin{bmatrix}
        -1/4  \\
        1 \\  \end{bmatrix} $

But this is wrong, and not sure where I made the error, or if my whole procedure is off. So I stopped here.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've done so far. Keep in mind that there are infinitely many possible eigenvectors.

Comment: If I do the same for my second Eigenvalue, I'll get another eigenvector. Now, if I join both eigenvectors, what is that? Is that my $P$ matrix?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Hmmm.. According to this assignment, $ P=\begin{bmatrix}
        -1/4 & -1/3  \\
        1 & 1 \\  \end{bmatrix} $ is wrong...Not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the solution as:

$$ A= P \cdot D \cdot P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1\\3 & 4\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -4 & 0\\0 & -3 \end{bmatrix}  \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -4 & -1\\3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Compare the eigenvalues\eigenvectors I wrote and the ones you wrote. So your answer is exactly the same as mine! Look at them closely and ask what you can change to make them look identical.

I would rather stay away from the fractions as they make my math more error prone (just a choice).

Does that make sense?

Comment: That actually worked. The assignment did not like having the eigenvector in a fraction form...Thank you.

Comment: @Dimitri: You are very welcome and you are doing great! When you write something to a negative power, you enclose it using ^ and squiggly brackets. Regards

Comment: OHH! Great, I was trying to figure out how to do that and I gave up! But for sure, I'll make sure not to leave stuff in fraction form.

Comment: Thanks for the up-votes! I don't so much care about the points, just ways to improve my writing of answers so they are clear and helpful!

Comment: I was the upvote and wanted to ask why the downvote - no explanation!

Comment: I end up second-guessing myself when I get downvotes. Especially when there's no comment or reason given. I've certainly received *well-deserved* downvotes...Oh well. I just have to learn not to take things personally :-/

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks my friend. $+^+$

Comment: @BabakS.: you are very welcome.